# How to prevent datatable from scrolling top when clicks on the button in the table column in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

[image]

When I clicks on any of the buttons, datatable automatically scrolls top.Is there any way to prevent it from scrolling top?

Comment: What does the action behind the buttons do? I mean, is the application doing a full page request or is the action processed by JavaScript (e.g. AJAX call)?

Comment: Downvote for not including any code/script

Comment: @Yun It's a large piece of code. More than that , rows are added when an event is called. Thats why I didn't added the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using **#** in **href** attribute, use **javascript:;** instead of **#**

```
for ex- <a href="javascript:;">text</a>
```